# What are the strongest 3D Object shape with which it is possible to fullfill a volume?

Tags: geometry, 3d

It's a derivative question of "[What are the only 3D objects with which it is possible to fullfill a volume?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2556604/what-are-the-only-3d-objects-with-which-it-is-possible-to-fullfill-a-volume)" and so the question only concerns these objects.

I feel cube and the object built with pentagon are some of them (if there are any others in regular polyhedra).

But answers can also consider what suggested Parcly, ie "There is a volume filling construction using a mix of regular tetrahedra and regular octahedra."

Kind Regards

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Question, here about polyhedra, is very similar to "What is the strongest structure or strongest shape under compression? [link](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-strongest-structure-or-strongest-shape-under-compression)" or "Is the triangle really the strongest geometric shape? [link](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskEngineers/comments/1c75k1/is_the_triangle_really_the_strongest_geometric/)"

Comment: How are you defining "strongest"?