# Covering the plane with convex polygons?

Tags: geometry, tiling

I have got the following task here:

Prove, that you can't cover the "Plane" with convex polygons, which have more than $\,6\,$ vertices!

The answer is pretty obvious for $\,n=3\,$ vertices, because  $   6\cdot 60^\circ = 360^\circ$.

For $\,n=4\,$ it works too, because $4\cdot 90^\circ = 360^\circ$.

I think that $\,n=6\,$ is good too, but how do I prove, that other than that, it isn't possible to do that?

Comment: $n=5$ is possible, but not with *regular* pentagons.

Comment: Are we allowed to mix $7$-, $8$-, and $9$-gons?  Are we allowed to have different (non-congruent) $7$-gons?  [pjs36 ruled all these interesting cases out...]

Comment: @GEdgar if you insist upon translational invariance as well, $n=5$ IS ruled out too.

Comment: You can't mix them, you can only use one type :)

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91761/why-a-tesselation-of-the-plane-by-a-convex-polygon-of-7-or-more-sides-is-not-pos?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you mean tiling the plane with copies of the same regular $n$-gon; so we can't mix squares and hexagons, for example.

Why are $60^\circ, 90^\circ,$ and $120^\circ$ (for a hexagon) important, feature of the polygon do they measure?

What the corresponding angles be, if we consider a regular $n$-gon, where $n > 6$? Would angles like that make sense, in a tiling situation?

Answer (score 0):

It *is* possible to cover the plane with convex polygons with more than $6$ vetices, if you do not put a bound on their size. Take [a tiling of the hyperbolic plane by heptagons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heptagonal_tiling) in the disc model and apply a map $(r,\theta)\mapsto(\frac{r}{1-r},\theta)$ to yield a tiling of the whole plane (if we straighten out the edges after applying the transformation).

If you do bound the area and perimeter of such heptagons, it can't be done - see [this /r/mathriddles thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/mathriddles/comments/jqgkml/heptagon_tiling/) for a proof.