# Equilateral polygon plane tiling

Tags: geometry, tiling

From playing around with some toothpicks and peas, I think that it should be possible to prove that the plane cannot be tiled by a possibly infinite set of equilateral polygons with the same number of sides whenever $n>6$, though I am not sure regarding $n=5$.

Is there a simple proof / contradiction to the above?

Comment: When $n$ is too large, you can calculate the angles and see that the polygons can't fit around a single point.  You could also use the Euler characteristic on a finite (but large) tiling.

Comment: @michaelBurr: Hence the claim. The generalization to $n$ got a bit messy though.

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91761/why-a-tesselation-of-the-plane-by-a-convex-polygon-of-7-or-more-sides-is-not-pos?rq=1)

Comment: As Dan Rust's answer shows, the claim is false for equilateral polygons, but it is true for regular polygons (which have equal angles in addition to equal sides).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just crinkle the edges of a square. This will at least let you form an equilateral $2n$-gon for any $n\geq 2$.

[image]

For $n$ an odd numbers of edges just have a church with $(n-3)/2$ `steeples'.

You can clearly tile the plane with such shapes.
[image]

Comment: I don't see how that proves anything about whether or not you can tile the plane.

Comment: @nbubis: ??? Just take the first diagram and fill the plane with it.

Comment: For the second diagram, line them up side by side, and then construct an identical line, but upside down.  These sawtooths will meet and create a single straight stripe.  This allows you to tile the plane as well.

Comment: Slow morning :) Thank you!