# How can the disc intersect $\geq$ $10^9$ $7-\text {gons}$?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

Given an arbitrary disc with radius $200$ on a plane that's been divided into convex $7-$gons each with radius $\leq \frac{1}{2}$, show that it intersects $\geq$ $10^9$ $7-\text {gons}$?

Now, how is this even possible? Since it's a disc, we can consider circles both inside and on the peripheri of the disc. 
So, considering the area, we get $< 2.10^5$ $7-$gons which intersect and also we have some more polygons that intersect on the sides. How does that make up to $10^9$?

Comment: Just to remove confusion, the number is $10^9$ and it shouldn't be mistaken for $10^9~7$. The $7$ is there adjoined with next word **"-gon"**.

Comment: There are ways to tile the plane with non-congruent convex heptagons, see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91761/why-a-tesselation-of-the-plane-by-a-convex-polygon-of-7-or-more-sides-is-not-pos).  The point, I think, is that most of the heptagons will have very small areas.  However, I don't know how to quantify this to obtain the desired estimate.

Comment: heptagon is the name of a $7$-gon.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Yes, it's not really trivial to quantify this. I can somewhat understand and as they're pretty small, such a vague way of area ratio that I have considered missed out a lot of heptagons as my way doesn't ensure the fact that the heptagons are adjacent to each other. I have considered them as circle and got such a poor bound.

Comment: You mention _disc_ (__not__ circle) but also _intersect_ instead of _(partially) cover_. What do you mean for a disc to _intersect_ a heptagon? Did you mean _(partially) cover_? Or did you mean that the boundary of the disc (the circle) intersects at least one edge of the heptagon?

Comment: @orlp Honestly, I am not sure of that. I have just copied the question. I have assumed that it means **"cover"** as just intersection along the circumference won't yield such a great value. Also, had it been the case, the question would have used the word "circle" instead of "disc". That's what I believe.

Comment: It's easy to prove a lower bound of roughly $160,000$ heptagons based on circle packing.

Comment: Also do the heptagons have to be _convex_?

Comment: @orlp Yes, I have done that circle packing and that comes to be the lower bound but that's extremely weak. And yes, as mentioned, the heptagons are to be **convex**

Comment: Where are you copying the question from?

Comment: @RobertIsrael Some random question paper

Comment: Anyone with any stronger bound?